# Astronomical symbols in LaTeX dwarf planet Vesta and Ceres

Tags: symbols, packages

What package is need to make the Vesta symbol in LaTeX?

I am using `wasysym` (maybe misspelled here) package which generates `\earth` and the other planets.

However, I would like the symbol for Vesta and Ceres.

Comment: Use the `starfont` package

Answer (score 5):

From the `starfont` package manual:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{starfont}
\newcommand{\showboth}[1]{\starfontsans #1 & \starfontserif #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llll|llll}
\verb|\Ceres| & \showboth{\Ceres} & Ceres &
\verb|\Vesta| & \showboth{\Vesta} & Vesta 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here is my screen shot:

[image]

Comment: only an underscore appears for me when I use `\Vesta`

Comment: I am using TeXLive 2012 on Linux running through emacs on the terminal with AucTex running the compilation through Latexmk.